# Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, react-native

I create a const `backText` that return a `<Text />` and put it into `render`, but it doesn't show out.

I think it should work, but it shows the yellow warning

> Functions are not valid as a React child.

Here is my `render`

```
render() {
    const backText = () => {
      return (
        <Text>Test</Text>
      );
    };

        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#B0E0E6' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.9, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <Text>Three !</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 0.1, alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 15 }}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ffffff" />
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, marginTop: 8, color: 'gray' }}>Loading...</Text>
              {backText}
            </View>

          </View>
        );
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
backText = () => {
  return (
    <Text>Test</Text>
  );
}

render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#B0E0E6' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.9, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <Text>Three !</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 0.1, alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 15 }}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ffffff" />
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, marginTop: 8, color: 'gray' }}>Loading...</Text>
              {this.backText()}
            </View>

          </View>
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It work !  I had tried the code like yours before. The different is between `this.backText` and `this.backText()`. Thank you @Ali

Comment: What you are saying is not quite correct. Of course you can have more code in render than just a return and you can define functions inside render.

Comment: @FelixKling You are right. i edit my answer... Thanks :-)